# Get post ancestors in the Block Editor

Tags: block-editor

I need to get the highest-level ancestor of the current page in the Block Editor.

I can use

```
wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostAttribute('parent');
```

to get the immediate parent of the current page, but is there anything like the PHP `get_post_ancestors()` that gets all the ancestors back to the top-level page?

I've tried the following in the block, but this doesn't actually get the ID of the top ancestor:

```
const findParent = (ancestor) => {
    let ancestorData = wp
        .apiFetch({ path: 'wp/v2/pages/' + ancestor })
        .then((newData) => {
            if (newData.parent > 0) {
                while (ancestorData.parent > 0) {
                    wp.apiFetch({
                        path: 'wp/v2/pages/' + ancestorData.parent,
                    }).then((moreData) => {
                        ancestorData = moreData;
                    });
                }
            }
            return ancestorData.id;
        });
};

// Default (directChildren attribute is true): get children of the current page.
let ancestor = select('core/editor').getCurrentPostId();
if (false === directChildren) {
    // If directChildren attribute is false, get children of the highest ancestor page.
    ancestor = findParent(ancestor);
}
```

Comment: you would need to take that parent ID then fetch that post, then keep repeating that process until the parent ID is zero, which is very close to what `get_post_ancestors` does. What do you require this information for? Can you add some context?

Comment: I'm making a block that lists the top ancestor's children. I was hoping there was a function to find the top ancestor rather than repeat until the parent is 0, but that will do if there isn't a more efficient method.

Comment: it's what `get_post_ancestors` does internally, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/ it has a `while ( $ancestor = get_post( $post->post_parent ) )` that appends to an array until nothing is found then calls `break;`, there's no shortcut that bypasses that in the APIs, even in PHP. I'm not 100% sure how i'd code that up, else I'd write up an answer with an example

Comment: Just to be sure, this will be called from within a component, correct? 

Comment: So far the above code is just within the block's `edit` function. Once `ancestor` is finalized, there's a `useSelect()` to get the children of the ancestor, and at the end in the `return()` an array map to output each as a `<li>` or `<div>` depending on block style. I can add more of the code if needed, just thought the stripped-down chunk above might be less confusing than pasting the whole block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***August 20, 2022 Update:** For completeness, I added a JavaScript/Gutenberg solution which does what the `findParent()` function in question tries to do, i.e. find the top ancestor. You can find the code below the "Original Answer" section.*

---

### Original Answer

The block editor doesn't (currently) have a function equivalent to [`get_post_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/), and yes you could create such function on your own, but an easy way to get the first/highest-level ancestor without having to manually make multiple or even any REST API (or HTTP) requests, is:

1. [Use a custom REST API **field**](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#adding-custom-fields-to-api-responses) (and just for certain post types like `page` in your case)

   This way, you wouldn't need to make any additional API/HTTP requests and for the current Page/post, simply read from the post data that has already been fetched by the block editor.
2. [Or use a custom REST API **endpoint**](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

#### Working Examples

1. Using a custom REST field named `first_parent`, but just use any other name you like:

   ```php
   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_rest_field' );
   function my_register_rest_field() {
       register_rest_field( 'page', 'first_parent', array(
           'get_callback' => function ( $post_arr ) {
               $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post_arr['id'] );
               return (int) array_pop( $ancestors );
           },
       ) );
   }
   ```

   So with that, you could simply call the `getCurrentPostAttribute()` to get the very first ancestor:

   ```js
   wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostAttribute( 'first_parent' );
   ```
2. Using a custom REST API endpoint which returns the first ancestor of a post, just like the above `first_parent` field:

   ```php
   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_rest_route' );
   function my_register_rest_route() {
       register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v1', '/first-parent/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
           'methods'             => 'GET',
           'callback'            => function ( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
               $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $request['id'] );
               return (int) array_pop( $ancestors );
           },
           'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
       ) );
   }
   ```

   So with that, you just need to make a fetch request to `my-plugin/v1/first-parent/<post id>`, e.g. `https://example.com/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/first-parent/123`, and you'll get the very first ancestor of the post.

   ```js
   wp.apiFetch( {
       path: 'my-plugin/v1/first-parent/123',
   } ).then(
       parent => console.log( parent ),
       error => console.log( error )
   );
   ```

And if you want, your endpoint could return an array of ancestors instead and use JS to get the first ancestor (which is the last item, if you used `get_post_ancestors()`).

---

### Update: A (custom) JavaScript/Gutenberg Solution

I decided to try with `useSelect()` and `getEntityRecord()`, and I thought you might want to try it out or maybe just check the code :)

- **Note:** `parentId` is the ID of the parent of the current post (i.e. the post's `post_parent` value), so if it's not a `0`, i.e. it's not a top-level post, then we'll find its first ancestor. As for the rest like how/where `firstParentId` should be used, see the *sample implementation* below.

```js
const firstParentId = useSelect( select => {
    const { getEntityRecord } = select( 'core' );

    const findFirstParentId = ( id, type ) => {
        const post = getEntityRecord( 'postType', type, id );

        // If the post is a child post, i.e. it has a parent, fetch the parent
        // post. So we're making a recursive function call until the very first
        // parent is found.
        if ( post && undefined !== post.parent && post.parent > 0 ) {
            return findFirstParentId( post.parent, type );
        }

        // If we've found the top ancestor, return its ID.
        return post ? post.id : -1;
    };

    return parentId ? findFirstParentId( postId, postType ) : -1;
}, [ postId, postType, parentId ] );
```

**Sample Implementation** (tested working in WordPress v6.0.1)

So this is the entire code in my block's `edit()` function which displays the very first ancestor's ID and followed by a `UL` list of the ancestors *including* the current post:

```js
const { postId, postType, parentId } = useSelect( select => {
    const {
        getCurrentPostId,
        getCurrentPostType,
        getCurrentPostAttribute,
    } = select( 'core/editor' );

    return {
        postId: getCurrentPostId(),
        postType: getCurrentPostType(),
        parentId: getCurrentPostAttribute( 'parent' ),
    };
}, [] );

const { firstParentId, theParents, isResolved } = useSelect( select => {
    const { getEntityRecord } = select( 'core' );

    const theParents = [];
    // this is true if the current post has no parent, or that we've found the
    // top ancestor
    let isResolved   = ( ! parentId );

    const findFirstParentId = ( id, type ) => {
        const post = getEntityRecord( 'postType', type, id );

        // If the request has been resolved and the post data is good, then
        // we add the post to the parent pages array. Each item contains the
        // post ID and title. I.e. array( <ID>, <Title> )
        post && theParents.push( [ post.id, post.title?.rendered ] );

        // If the post is a child post, i.e. it has a parent, fetch the parent
        // post. So we're making a recursive function call until the very first
        // parent is found.
        if ( post && undefined !== post.parent && post.parent > 0 ) {
            return findFirstParentId( post.parent, type );
        }

        isResolved = ( !! post );

        // If we've found the top ancestor, return its ID.
        return post ? post.id : -1;
    };

    return {
        firstParentId: parentId ? findFirstParentId( postId, postType ) : -1,
        theParents,
        // use this instead to display the top ancestor first
//      theParents: theParents.reverse(),
        isResolved,
    };
}, [ postId, postType, parentId ] );

return (
    <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
        <p>
            Current Post ID: { postId } (type: { postType })<br />
            Top Ancestor ID: {
                isResolved ? ( firstParentId >= 0 ? firstParentId : 'None' ) :
                'Loading..'
            }
        </p>

        <h3>Hierarchy</h3>
        { ! isResolved && ( <p>Loading..</p> ) }
        { isResolved && theParents.length ? (
            <ul>
                { theParents.map( ( [ id, title ] ) => (
                    <li key={ 'page-' + id }>{ title } (ID: { id })</li>
                ) ) }
            </ul>
        ) : <p>None?</p> }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Those both work beautifully! I had thought about adding the data to the REST API, but hadn't tackled how to do that yet. The custom field on Pages looks like a great fit for my needs.

Comment: I also thought so, but yes, it would be nice if there was a core JS solution in Gutenberg.. :) Also, if you want, you can restrict the field only to certain users, e.g. administrators only.

Comment: Thanks a million for accepting my answer :) And I actually had planned to add a JS solution (without using a custom REST API field/endpoint), but didn't have a chance to do so earlier on. But I've now added it and hopefully it helps!

Comment: Thank you for adding that! It's very similar to what I was playing around with but could never get to work. I hope all these options help someone else as much as they have helped me! :)

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit of an experiment - I thought it might be better to use the `core` store's `getEntityRecord()` to fetch post records rather than directly using the REST API, in order to leverage the entity cache in state.

But resolving ancestors necessitates a number of asynchronous operations executed in sequence, and my hook-based solution has ended up feeling a little ugly and a wee-bit clunky to me as a result:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const useCurrentPostAncestorRecords = () => {
  const post_type = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
    []
  );

  const [ { ancestor_records, loading }, setState ] = useState(
    { ancestor_records: [], loading: true }
  );

  // Retrieve the post's parent from editor state in case it changes, or hasn't been persisted to the db.
  const immediate_parent_id = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'parent' )
  );

  const next_parent_id = ancestor_records.length > 0
    ? ancestor_records[0].parent
    : immediate_parent_id;

  const next_parent_record = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'postType', post_type, next_parent_id ),
    [ post_type, next_parent_id ]
  );

  // If the post parent changes, reset the ancestor list.
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setState( { ancestor_records: [], loading: !!immediate_parent_id } );
    },
    [ immediate_parent_id ]
  );

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // If we've already hit a parentless post, skip processing.
      if( !loading )
        return;

      // If the next parent ID is 0, indicate completion.
      if( next_parent_id == 0 ) {
        setState( ( state ) => ({ ...state, loading: false }) );
        return;
      }

      // If the next parent record has loaded into state, add it to the list.
      if( next_parent_record?.id ) {
        setState( ({ ancestor_records }) => ({
          ancestor_records: [ next_parent_record, ...ancestor_records ],
          loading: !!next_parent_record.parent,
        }) );
      }
    },
    [ loading, next_parent_id, next_parent_record ]
  );

  return { records: ancestor_records, loading };
}
```

The hook above might be used in a component as such:

```js
  const ancestors = useCurrentPostAncestorRecords();

  return (
    <ul>
      { !ancestors.loading && ancestors.records.map( ( { id, title } ) => (
        <li key={id}>{title.rendered}</li>
      ) ) }
    </ul>
  );
```

I think there a lot of ways in which this could be improved (and I'd love to hear any suggestions!) - maybe by using/emulating `useSuspenseSelect()` to avoid some of the unnecessary renders, and introducing some sort of error handling for the case of a bad parent ID - but ultimately I might prefer an API-based approach sheerly for the elegance of being able to wrap up the full ancestral resolution into a single asynchronous promise.

Comment: I might double back a bit later to add an API-based implementation, just out of curiosity for the comparison.

Comment: `getEntityRecord()` certainly feels more natural, I just could not get it to work for the life of me because it required so many recursive callbacks. I think this way would work if I fine-tuned a bit more, and it's an excellent and much-appreciated suggestion. I would be very curious to see an API-based approach if you feel inclined to write one. :)

Comment: Yeah! I really like the idea of `getEntityRecord()` on paper - but am a bit dismayed about how it works for this application in practice. It's really not a troubling number of additional renders (~3 base + 2ish per ancestor) - especially considering that it'll only be constructing an ancestor list once and thereafter only when the post parent changes - it just irks my inner code monkey that it feels so roundabout and that I'm not really sure how to further reduce renders. TL;DR the code's probably fine, but it hurt my feelings :P